# in_array() does not seem to check after key 2

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple function that should just give me TRUE or FALSE if a value is find in an array.

```
function bypass($user, $bypassUsers){
    $users = explode(",", $bypassUsers);
    // trim($users);

    if(in_array($user,$users)){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

While to me everything looks of when I have more than 2 values in the array, the function returns FALSE as if `in_array()` does not see from key [2].

Any idea?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided us with arrays to test against

Comment: That `trim` call is both superfluous and invalid on an *array*.

Comment: $bypassUsers is a string.

`$bypassUsers = "admin,webmaster,name";`

if a user has the username "name" the function returns false, if I put name in the first position, the function returns true...

Comment: Without it does the same, I thought maybe I have some white spaces or things that disturb. you can remove it.

Comment: Testing with that list, it returns `true` for me regardless of the order of the names.  We'd love to see an *actual* call (and the check of its return value) from a failing case.

Comment: It was returning false because of the white spaces. `$bypassUsers = 'user, user2, user3'` this was not working but this was `$bypassUsers = 'user,user2,user3'`, thus I needed to trim each user as the string was coming from a text field in joomla admin. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to apply trim to all elements, instead of:

```
$users = explode(",", $bypassUsers);
trim($users);
```

You should do this instead:

```
$users = array_map('trim', explode(',', $bypassUsers));
```

It applies `trim()` to the result of `explode()`. Afterwards, you can return the result in one statement:

```
return in_array($user, $users, true); 
// third argument determines whether to use == or === for comparison
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function bypass($user, $bypassUsers){
    $users = explode(",", $bypassUsers);
    foreach($users as $key=>$usr){
        $users[$key] = trim($usr);
    }

    if(in_array(trim($user),$users)){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Trim is the problem because it works with string not with an array